# Close Blast Targeting Options

Tags: dnd-4e

The Rules Compendium (and Player's Handbook) provides two examples of how to use a Close Blast 3.
[image] and [image]

Where w is the wizard casting [Thunderwave](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=1169) (for example).  These are the options my group has used.  A recent rereading of the rules has led us to ask if the below is valid.

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that's valid. As long as one of the blast's squares is adjacent to your character, it's a legal placement.

> A blast fills an area adjacent to you that is a specified number of squares on a side.

Your example is the specified number of squares (three), and it is adjacent to the caster.